# .contains only showing 1 contains when there is more

Tags: c#

I've been coding this small project. the problem is there is more than 1 of them in the textbox and it's only adding "a" once. I don't understand why? what do you guys recommend I change in my code?

```
if (textBox3.Text.Contains("LKFKEOFK"))
{
    textBox4.AppendText("a");
}
```

Comment: Because it literally answers question “does this string contain that string”, not “how many times does this string contain that string.” You could use `IndexOf` with an offset based on the previous found location

Comment: [How to count of sub-string occurrences?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15577464)

Comment: You are checking once, then adding once. What's the mystery here?

Answer (score 2):

```
   int i = 0;
   while ((i = textBox3.Text.IndexOf("LKFKE0FK", i, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) != -1)
   {
       i += "LKFKE0FK".Length;
       textBox4.AppendText("a");
   }
```

Edited:

```
        List<Tuple<int, string>> tupleList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        int i = 0;
        while ((i = textBox3.Text.IndexOf("LKFKE0FK", i, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) != -1)
        {
            i += "LKFKE0FK".Length;
            tupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(i, "a"));
        }

        int j = 0;
        while ((j = textBox3.Text.IndexOf("LDMWICB", j, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) != -1)
        {
            j += "LDMWICB".Length;
            tupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(j, "b"));
        }

        tupleList.Sort();

        for (int k = 0; k < tupleList.Count; k++)
        {
            textBox4.AppendText(tupleList.ElementAt(k).Item2);
        }
```

Comment: works but it isnt coming out the correct way, in the right order. i have another value asiigned so i did this for both and there are not in the same order i put them in for example a b a b a b comes at as aaabbb

Comment: @MrCoInSanity are you trying to search both values at the same time? and then whatever order the values are found in, that's the ordered they get printed out (ababab)?

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox4.AppendText(new string('a', Regex.Matches(textBox3.Text, "LKFKEOFK").Count));
```

Or, if you want to add a whole string for each occurrence run

```
textBox4.AppendText(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ab", Regex.Matches(textBox3.Text, "LKFKEOFK").Count)));
```

Requires your LKFKEOFK not to contain any [RegEx relevant characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)

Comment: well, when i use this code textBox4.AppendText(new string('a', Regex.Matches(textBox3.Text, "LKFKEOFK").Count));
            textBox4.AppendText(new string('b', Regex.Matches(textBox3.Text, "LDMWICB").Count)); it shows all of them it just aint showing in the right order. i hope you understand

Comment: Then use `textBox4.AppendText(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ab", Regex.Matches(textBox3.Text, "LKFKEOFK").Count)));` if you have multiple characters

Comment: i need b to be equal to something else if that makes sense. so it gives b instead of ab with just LKFKEOFK

Comment: @MrCoInSanity Ok I understand, then my solution does technically not work for you, the idea of Harminder Kaur will me more suiteable for you.

Comment: neither his is :(

Comment: @MrCoInSanity but his can be extended to do that, while my can not